# Maximum number of columns shown when formatting DataFrames in python-polars?

Tags: python-polars

how set maximum number of columns shown when formatting DataFrames ?

i found that in rust-polars i need to modify `"POLARS_FMT_MAX_COLS"` env variable.
how can i do this in python ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`polars.Config.set_tbl_cols`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_tbl_cols.html)